# Sublime Text 3 "toggle block comment" no longer comments out entire CSS selector

Tags: css, sass, sublimetext3, comments

I haven't used ST for some months and I am quite certain that it used to comment/uncomment the entire CSS selector when using `ctrl+shift+/` ("toggle block comment") with the cursor inside said selector, but nothing actually selected.

Is anybody aware of what could have caused this behaviour to be replaced with simply adding `/*  */` around the cursor?

I've tried using `SCSS` mode(which is what I usually use) and vanilla `CSS` mode.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was actually looking for was [Emmet](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet)'s "toggle comment" command which, in the case of CSS, toggles commenting the entire selector. I believe it's with an update to the respective package that the behaviour changed and stopped hooking into `ctrl+shift+/`, but I could be wrong.

I ended up adding a keyboard shortcut for said command in `Preferences > Key Bindings`, like so:

```
    {
        "keys": ["alt+/"],
        "command": "emmet_toggle_comment"
    },
```

Comment: Since it's an entirely different command, you can just use whatever key binding you want. You could also swap the default key bindings as well, if you want to line comment with the block comment key.

Comment: Indeed, but I preferred keeping sublime's default `toggle block comment` shortcut aswell. It behaves differently from emmet's `toggle comment`, sometimes in more useful ways.

Answer (score 1):

There are two bindings for toggling comments, and the one you're using is the one meant for block comments when you probably mean to be using the one for line comments instead. That's not something that's been changed in recent memory.

The keys involved are different depending on platform, but for our purposes here:

- <kbd>Ctrl+/</kbd> is bound to `toggle_comment` with `block` set to `false`
- <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+/</kbd> is bound to `toggle_comment` with `block` set to `true`

Potentially confusing here is the notion that the `/* */` style comments of CSS are actually block comments, which might make you think that you need the second binding.

Actually, the value of the argument controls what gets commented with whatever comment delimiters the support package for the language defines. It's possible for a language (such as C++) to define different comment delimiters for different styles, but that's not required.

When block is set to `true`, the commented area is the selected text, whereas when it's `false` it's the line the caret(s) are sitting on.

So, assuming the sample css:

```css
body {
    color: red;
}
```

If the cursor is sitting on the `:` and you use <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+/</kbd>, the result is the following, because the selection is wrapped but the selection is empty (which visually looks like the selection is wrapping the caret).

```css
body {
    color/**/: red;
}
```

On the other hand, with the cursor in the same place and using <kbd>Ctrl+/</kbd> the result is:

```css
body {
    /*color: red;*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I am aware of all that and it is not waht I was asking.